how to plot a stacked, dodge geom_bar
I was working on a barplot and I would need to plot next to each other with dodge two set of observations (the reads threshold) for the same sample; additionally, each on of them had been evaluated with two approaches one of which should expectedly yield higher values.
I also wish to stack the two approaches with different alpha so that the one with a higher count, if given a lighter alpha value, should come slightly on top of the other by a certain margin.
I had some issues and found this post where in the last message they seem to be doing something similar, but I'm not sure whether is working correctly with my data/I implemented it correctly.The best result I achieved with my code is the following; however, I need the Q20 and primary to be dodged for the same sample...
Here is the code I'm using:
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

### IMPORT THE DATASET
reads_count <- read_excel("/pat/to/file.xlsm", 14)

reads_count$threshold <- factor(reads_count$threshold, levels=c('Q20', 'primary'))

### PLOT THE DATA
plot <- 
  ggplot(reads_count) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=sample, y=count, fill=threshold, alpha=approach), stat="identity", position="stack") + 
  
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c("maf"=.75, "per"=.50)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(9, "RdPu")[c(4, 6)]) +
  
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') +
  
  guides(
    fill=guide_legend(title="reads threshold", title.position="top", title.hjust=.5),
    alpha=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=c("black","black")), title="approach", title.position="top", title.hjust=.5)
  ) +
  
  xlab("")

plot + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1))

and a dput of a subset of my data:
structure(list(sample = c("abh100", "abh100", "abh100", "abh100", 
"abh107", "abh107", "abh107", "abh107", "ALB212", "ALB212", "ALB212", 
"ALB212", "Ale14", "Ale14", "Ale14", "Ale14", "Ale20", "Ale20", 
"Ale20", "Ale20", "Ale22", "Ale22", "Ale22", "Ale22", "Ale32", 
"Ale32", "Ale32", "Ale32", "altai363p", "altai363p", "altai363p", 
"altai363p"), approach = c("maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", 
"per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", 
"maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", 
"per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per", "maf", "per"
), threshold = c("primary", "primary", "Q20", "Q20", "primary", 
"primary", "Q20", "Q20", "primary", "primary", "Q20", "Q20", 
"primary", "primary", "Q20", "Q20", "primary", "primary", "Q20", 
"Q20", "primary", "primary", "Q20", "Q20", "primary", "primary", 
"Q20", "Q20", "primary", "primary", "Q20", "Q20"), count = c(1187029476, 
1187029476, 1035706720, 1037073291, 1137440782, 1137440782, 1004893337, 
1006220437, 1144644504, 1144644504, 1005977236, 1007477030, 1453531262, 
1453531262, 1271470710, 1273176138, 1164587046, 1164587046, 1046011290, 
1047432988, 1409599972, 1409599972, 1261086124, 1262719714, 1372877904, 
1372877904, 1195152421, 1196509505, 1222840858, 1222840858, 1051092230, 
1052736035)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))

I'm not entirely sure even tweaking the code I'm using will lead to the expected result; in fact, stacking simply heaps the two approaches, whereas I would need to share the same count up to the point they match then the higher one should come on top for the difference, as in the example from the post. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!
